# Should HTML element classes have prefixes depending on their use?

Tags: javascript, html, css, coding-style

I've been told that it's standard practice to prefix class names on HTML elements with "jq" or "js" so that the designer doesn't conflict with the developer.

I've been around a little and I've never seen this done and personally feel this creates an artificial and unhelpful divide between design and code.

The question is whether this is indeed standard practice, and moreover, I would like references to articles explaining *why* this is done (what problem does it solve).

Comment: Companies can have pretty weird policies on these things. I once worked in a company where there was a policy on using IDs to style pages for the same reason. Seems quite unreasonable to me.

Comment: @Jakub - that sounds ridiculous! :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a general standard practice, but it may be a standard practive within a specific organisation.

Using prefixes to specify usage of an identifier is called hungarian notation. It's mostly used to specify data types in script languages without strict typing, but the original intention was just to specify any aspect that was crucial to the use of the identifier.

Using prefixes like that can be useful to make sure that classes intended for design doesn't conflict with classes intended for program control. It's however not dependant on who is creating the class, but how the class is used. If a developer creates a script that adds a class to elements to change their appearence, the class is used for design so it should not be prefixed as a program control class name. A class name used for program control would only be used for that, and have no visual style applied to it.

As with most programming practices, it's more important that you pick a standard and stick to it, than picking the standard that is absolutely best.

Answer (score 15):

I'm the front-end developer at my organisation and as such am responsible for the CSS.  I create all the required classes for layout and UI, as well as periodically tidying up unused styles and mark-up.

Our developers never need to add classes for presentation, but they do occasionally add classes for Javascript.  In these instances I have asked them to prepend their classes with `js-`.

This simply helps me identify classes that are not used for presentation, but are still required for functionality.  My other class names are all descriptive of the content.

Before we introduced this it was much harder to keep the mark-up tidy (by removing unused classes) as classes could seem redundant (with no references in the stylesheets), but were still used.

I've not come across any documentation saying this is a bad idea.  It works for us, so is simply a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an old fashioned convention for me especially in context with html/javscript/css.

Classes should only be used for layout reasons. If there are classes anyway, defined by a designer, then they can and should be used by developers. Values for pure programm controls should be defined using custom attributes (http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml). This practice together with detailed and well-thought-out naming conventions mostly avoid problems.

It also sounds like classes would have to be assigned to elements twice often with this prefix pratice. One more reason to ask how a practice like that can be a good or even standard one.

---

Edit:
Prefixes can be useful inside plugins for e.g. javascript libraries of course to avoid class conflicts!

Comment: The problem with this approach, much as I like it (hence the +1 vote), is that selection of elements by data attribute is significantly slower than class selection. See http://jsperf.com/attribute-vs-class-selection for the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it not standard practice (except, presumably, in your organisation), but the [W3C advises against it](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames). Class names should be used to further describe the contents of semantic HTML tags, rather than as reference points for design *or* development.

I would expect well-structure HTML pages to have consistent classes for similar content types which would be perfectly suitable for JavaScript usage.

A designer who cannot write HTML correctly, remembering that the HTML markup is supposed to describe the content *not style it*, should not be writing HTML IMO.

Comment: I think that W3C article is purely talking about class names from a presentational point of view, whereas classes are now commonly used as jQuery hooks with no visual use.  I don't read that article and think the W3C advise against prefixes for non-presentational classes.

Comment: @John Catterfeld: I disagree. The article is entitled "Use class with semantics in mind" after all. Also FTA: "... name your classes [...] with the role a certain HTML element of that class has".

Answer (score 0):

I've certainly not heard of this as a 'standard' practice.  Reading guidelines and articles, I have never seen a prefix infront of a class.

However, it might be handy prefixing a class name if you were going to use that class with jQuery.  It will be easier to identify and also it would let others know that it used by a function.